# Is it possible to setup replication between MySQL and MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I do have one Master MySQL Server running on Windows Server2008 and another is MariaDB 10.2 running on Linux(centos). Is it possible to replicate Database From Master MySQL server to MariaDB by setting up replication?

Answer (score 0):

It should work because MariaDB is drop-in replacement for MySQL. Just make sure that at least major version number is the same because newer versions can have backwards incompatible changes.